# Temporary data type casting for a single Query

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

Alright,  I realize that what I am about to ask may not be possible, which I can live with. But If it is possible it will make my life a lot easier.

Within my MS Access Database, I am attempting to query 2 tables. These tables are both linked to my Access DB, one is linked to an Excel file (`MSSB Reps DTP`) containing a dump from a seperate DB2 database.
The other table in my query (`SalesPage DNK Rep Query`) is linked to another Access DB, which is in turn linked to a SQL databse. Here is an image of the Query design screen:

[image: My Accdb Query Design Screen]

Where the tables are linked is not so much important as the fact that since they are linked tables, and since this is MS Access, I can not edit the tables. Therefore, I can not simply pop into design mode of either table and change the data type of a given column.

Each table has a column named `CRD Number`. I want to create an inner join between these two tables based on this column. Just a simple, everyday, inner join. I can not however, because the `CRD Number` column is stored as a Number for the `MSSB Reps DTP` table, and as text in the SalesPage DNK Rep Query table.

I was wondering if there is some way to temporarily use a fucntion to "cast" the `CRD Number` column fromo the `MSSB Reps DTP` table as text, so that I can run this query. However, any solution will be appreciated. Just don't tell me to edit the Excel document. I am trying very hard to avoid that for various reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `CStr` to cast the number as text.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM
    [MSSB Reps DTP] AS m
    INNER JOIN [SalesPage DNK Rep Query] AS s
    ON CStr(m.[CRD Number]) = s.[CRD Number];
```

The Access query designer may refuse to display that join in Design View, but you can switch to SQL View and edit the statement text.

Comment: Fantastic. I will give this a try and report back.

Comment: Alright, I got it working. I had a problem when I attempted to use the function the first time, because each table's `CRD Number column` can contain null values. I simply added the `is not null` criteria to my `Where` clause and that prevented the possibility of null values from each table. `

Comment: Here is the code that I ended up using: `FROM [SalesPage DNK Rep Query] INNER JOIN [MSSB Reps DTP] ON [SalesPage DNK Rep Query].CRD_NUMBER = CStr([MSSB Reps DTP].[Crd Number]) WHERE ((([SalesPage DNK Rep Query].CRD_NUMBER) Is Not Null) AND (([MSSB Reps DTP].[Crd Number]) Is Not Null));`